# Why does submultiplicativity hold for the Hilbert-Schmidt norm

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

I am trying to understand the following proof of submultiplicativity for the Hilbert-Schmidt norm defined as
$$\|A\|_{HS}=\text{tr}((A^\star A))^\frac{1}{2}$$
for $n\times n$ matrices $A$ of complex-valued indices.

Note that     $$\|A\|_{HS}=\left(\operatorname{tr}\left(A^{*} A\right)\right)^{1 / 2}=\left(\sum_{i=1}^{n}\left[\sum_{j=1}^{n} \overline{a_{i j}} a_{i j}\right]\right)^{1 / 2}=\left(\sum_{i=1}^{n} \sum_{j=1}^{n}\left|a_{i j}\right|^{2}\right)^{\frac{1}{2}}.$$

Now the proof I am confused about proceeds as follows

$$
\begin{aligned}
\|A B\|_{HS} &\\
=\left(\sum_{i, j=1}^{n}\left|\sum_{k=1}^{n} a_{i k} b_{k j}\right|^{2}\right)^{1 / 2} \\
\leq\left(\sum_{i, j=1}^{n}\left(\sum_{k=1}^{n}\left|a_{i k}\right|^{2}\right)\left(\sum_{m=1}^{n}\left|b_{m j}\right|^{2}\right)\right)^{1 / 2} \\
&\\=\left(\sum_{i, k=1}^{n}\left|a_{i k}\right|^{2}\right)^{1 / 2}\left(\sum_{m, j=1}^{n}\left|b_{m j}\right|^{2}\right)^{1 / 2} & \qquad \text{How did they get this step?}\\
=\|A\|_{HS}\|B\|_{HS}
\end{aligned}
$$

I am wondering what the justification is for the marked step in the above inequalities.

Thank you

Comment: It holds for exactly the same reasons it holds in $\mathbb{R}^n$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first inequality is the Cauchy-Schwarz inequality.

The step where you have a question is better understood if you explicitly write the double sum and identify that the terms in $a_{ik}$ do not depend on the inner indices $m$ and $j$, so they can be moved outside the inner sums:
$$\begin{split}
\left(\sum_{i, j=1}^{n}\left(\sum_{k=1}^{n}\left|a_{i k}\right|^{2}\right)\left(\sum_{m=1}^{n}\left|b_{m j}\right|^{2}\right)\right)^{1 / 2} & = \left(\sum_{i=1}^{n}\sum_{j=1}^n\left(\sum_{k=1}^{n}\left|a_{i k}\right|^{2}\right)\left(\sum_{m=1}^{n}\left|b_{m j}\right|^{2}\right)\right)^{1 / 2} \\
&=\left(\sum_{i=1}^{n}\left(\sum_{k=1}^{n}\left|a_{i k}\right|^{2}\right)\sum_{j=1}^n\left(\sum_{m=1}^{n}\left|b_{m j}\right|^{2}\right)\right)^{1 / 2} \\
&=\left(\sum_{i=1}^{n}\left(\sum_{k=1}^{n}\left|a_{i k}\right|^{2}\right)\right)^{\frac 1 2}\left(\sum_{j=1}^n\left(\sum_{m=1}^{n}\left|b_{m j}\right|^{2}\right)\right)^{1 / 2} \\
\end{split}$$

Comment: Perfect thank you!

Comment: You're welcome!